Async python function as a C callback
I'm in a situation where I need to use a C library that calls a python function for IO purposes so I don't have to create a C equivalent for the IO.  The python code base makes extensive use of asyncio and all the IO goes through queues.  And the C code is loaded as a dll using ctypes  The problem is you can't await from a C callback.  Is there anyway to use an async python function as a C callback?
Below is essentially how it will work.  Is my only option to do something like the non_async_callback or is there someway to await from C using ctypes.
python
import asyncio
import time
import ctypes

DLL_PATH="./bin/test.dll"

dll = ctypes.CDLL(DLL_PATH)
incoming_queue=asyncio.Queue()
outgoing_queue=asyncio.Queue()

c_func =  ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_uint8, ctypes.c_uint8)

async def python_callback(test_num):
    await outgoing_queue.put(test_num)
    test_num = await incoming_queue.get()
    return test_num

def non_async_callback(test_num):
    while True:
        try:
            outgoing_queue.put_nowait(test_num)
            break
        except asyncio.QueueFull:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
   
    while True:
        try:
            test_num = incoming_queue.get_nowait(test_num)
            break 
        except asyncio.QueueFull:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue

    return test_num

# Called at some point during initialization
def setup_callback():
    dll.setup_callback(c_func(python_callback))

C
uint8_t (CALLBACK*)(uint8_t);
CALLBACK py_callback

void setup_callbacks(void* callback)
{
    py_callback = callback;
}

// Called from somewhere else in the C code.
uint8_t python_callback(uint8_t value)
{
    uint8_t result = py_callback(value);
    // Do something with result
}


I am not able to follow your program flow. You appear to be starting with Python code that invokes dll.setup_callback(c_func(python_callback)) (in your C code the function appears to be namedsetup_callbacks with an s at the end). After the call completes you are back in your Python code having set C variable py_callback in the DLL. But then how does C code get executed so that it can initiate a call back to Python code? This piece seems to be missing. Is it being executed from the same thread that the Python code is executing in?

You are executing dll.setup_callback(c_func(python_callback)), i.e. passing to C code an async Python function. But you cannot directly await an async function directly from C code, which is the reason for your post. So did you mean to pass instead non_async_callback? Also, non_async_callback is putting to outgoing_queue and getting from incoming_queue but python_callback is also putting and getting from these same queues. I don't get it.

This is cut down significantly from the actual program, please forgive any mistakes.  There are other places in the python code where I'd call C functions, those C functions will do some stuff, then use the python callback for just the IO, then back to C to finish handling the data.
The non-async_callback was just an example of a way I thought to do the the non-async function if there were no other options for calling an async function from the C code.  It's not actually used in the example, sorry for the confusion.

From a bit of searching, I believe
async def python_callback(test_num):
    await outgoing_queue.put(test_num)
    test_num = await incoming_queue.get()
    return test_num

can be wrapped with something like
loop = None  # No loop has been created initially

def non_async_callback(test_num):
    global loop

    if not loop:  # Only create a new loop on first callback
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

    test_num = loop.run_until_complete(python_callback(test_num))
    return test_num

If non_async_callback might be called concurrently from multiple threads, then just use:
def non_async_callback(test_num):
    test_num = asyncio.run(python_callback(test_num))
    return test_num

Update
Based on the OP's comment it appears that we initially have a Python script calling a C function and that C function ultimately results in a callback being invoked. Thus the callback is occurring on the same thread that the original Python script (and thus its event loop) is executing. Consequently, the problem becomes calling a Python coroutine from a regular Python function without blocking the current event loop. This requires creating a separate thread running a separate event loop:
import asyncio
import threading

# Create a new thread running a new event_loop:
_new_event_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

# Run the new event loop on a new daemon thread:
threading.Thread(target=_new_event_loop.run_forever, name="Async Runner", daemon=True).start()

async def python_callback(test_num):
    print('starting')
    await asyncio.sleep(1) # Emulate doing something
    print('ending')
    return test_num * test_num

def non_async_callback(test_num):
    # Invoke the callback on a different thread, since no
    # further awaits can be done on this thread until this
    # funtion returns:
    return asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(python_callback(test_num), _new_event_loop).result()

async def main():
    ...
    # Ultimately our callback gets invoked on the same thread:
    test_num = non_async_callback(4)
    print(test_num)

asyncio.run(main())

Prints:
starting
ending
16


I need to do some more testing but this seems to work.  Thanks!

I added an update since based on your comment it seemed to me you were saying that your Python script was calling C code and that C code was calling back to your Python code. If that is the case, then non_async_callback would be called on the same thread that already has a running event loop and you cannot then create a new event loop nor can you use the current running event loop, because an await statement will block indefinitely. If this is indeed your actual flow, you need to run python_callback on a new  event loop that is running in another thread using the code in the Update.

Credit for this answer goes to @Booboo. I only provide a launchpad, and they fleshed it out with edits.

Using asyncio directly with C callbacks, as in your example, is challenging because Python's asyncio-based await operations cannot be directly used in synchronous contexts like a C callback. However, you can work around this limitation by leveraging a thread-safe queue and a separate asyncio task to manage the interaction between Python's event loop and the synchronous C callback.
Here’s how you can address the problem:

Solution Overview:

Use a Synchronous Bridge for Callbacks:

Use a synchronous function (non_async_callback) as the C callback.
Add the callback's input to an asyncio queue to handle it asynchronously in the Python event loop.


Spawn an Async Task for Processing:

Create a long-running asyncio task that listens to the queue, processes items asynchronously, and sends the results back to the C code.


Thread-Safe Interaction with Asyncio:

Use asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe for interacting with the asyncio event loop from the C callback's synchronous context.




Code Implementation:
Python Code:
import asyncio
import ctypes
from concurrent.futures import Future

DLL_PATH = "./bin/test.dll"

dll = ctypes.CDLL(DLL_PATH)
incoming_queue = asyncio.Queue()
outgoing_queue = asyncio.Queue()

# Define the C callback type
c_func = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_uint8, ctypes.c_uint8)


class CallbackBridge:
    """Bridge for handling async callbacks with the C library."""
    
    def __init__(self, loop):
        self.loop = loop
        self.result_futures = {}

    def sync_callback(self, test_num):
        """Synchronous callback used by the C library."""
        future = Future()
        self.result_futures[test_num] = future
        
        # Put the test_num in the outgoing_queue
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(outgoing_queue.put(test_num), self.loop)

        # Wait for the result to be processed in the async task
        return future.result()

    async def process_incoming(self):
        """Asynchronous task to process outgoing_queue and send results."""
        while True:
            # Get test_num from the queue
            test_num = await outgoing_queue.get()
            
            # Simulate async processing (e.g., await python_callback())
            result = await self.python_callback(test_num)
            
            # Send the result back to the corresponding future
            if test_num in self.result_futures:
                self.result_futures[test_num].set_result(result)

    async def python_callback(self, test_num):
        """Simulate the async processing."""
        print(f"Processing {test_num} asynchronously")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)  # Simulate async I/O
        return test_num + 1  # Return some result


def setup_callback():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    # Create the callback bridge
    bridge = CallbackBridge(loop)

    # Start the async task to process the queue
    loop.create_task(bridge.process_incoming())

    # Assign the synchronous callback to the C library
    dll.setup_callback(c_func(bridge.sync_callback))


# Run the asyncio event loop
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(setup_callback())

C Code:
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef uint8_t (*CALLBACK)(uint8_t);
CALLBACK py_callback;

void setup_callback(void* callback) {
    py_callback = (CALLBACK)callback;
}

// Simulated function to call the Python callback
void simulate_python_callback() {
    uint8_t value = 42; // Example input
    uint8_t result = py_callback(value);
    printf("Callback result: %d\n", result);
}


Explanation:

CallbackBridge:

Handles the synchronous-to-asynchronous communication.
Maintains a result_futures dictionary to map input values to their corresponding Future objects.


sync_callback:

This is the synchronous callback passed to the C library.
It puts the input value into the outgoing_queue and waits for the result using a Future.


process_incoming:

An asyncio task that continuously listens to the outgoing_queue.
Processes each item asynchronously and sets the result back in the Future.


setup_callback:

Initializes the callback system and starts the asyncio task.




Key Points to Note:

Thread-Safe Interaction:

Use asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe to safely interact with the event loop from the synchronous C callback.


Non-blocking Async Processing:

The process_incoming task ensures that the event loop continues to run while processing items from the queue.


Result Management:

The Future objects allow the synchronous callback to wait for the asynchronous processing to complete.




Testing:

Compile and link the C code with the shared library.
Run the Python script to initialize the callback and test the integration.

This approach ensures you can handle async IO in Python while conforming to the synchronous nature of C callbacks.

First, asyncio.get_event_loop has been deprecated and you should avoid using it. Second, the argument to asyncio.run needs to be a coroutine, which setup_callback() definitely is not. It appears that you are missing the async keyword from this function definition.

I'm pretty sure this is a chatgpt response
